# Python Pandas: iloc with flexible column position

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following df

```
w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 B
2  5  8  4  2  3  1  2  8  3
5  1  4  3  8  3  1  2  3  5
```

I want to add column C. The value for C depends on the value in B and the corresponding column position (the "B-th" column).
Result should look like this:

```
w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 B C
2  5  8  4  2  3  1  2  8  3 4
5  1  4  3  8  3  1  2  3  5 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
df['C'] = df.values[np.arange(len(df)), df.B.values]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   w1  w2  w3  w4  w5  w6  w7  w8  w9  B  C
0   2   5   8   4   2   3   1   2   8  3  4
1   5   1   4   3   8   3   1   2   3  5  3
```

Comment: It can be simplified: df["C"]= df.values[df.index, df.B]

Answer (score 1):

If want match only `w` columns add [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) first, convert to numpy array and use indexing:

```
df['C'] = df.filter(like='w').values[np.arange(len(df)), df['B'].values]
print (df)
   w1  w2  w3  w4  w5  w6  w7  w8  w9  B  C
0   2   5   8   4   2   3   1   2   8  3  4
1   5   1   4   3   8   3   1   2   3  5  3
```

Or if want match by numbers after `w` use [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html), but is necessary change `B` values with add `1`, convert to strings and prepend `w`:

```
df['C'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['B'].add(1).astype(str).radd('w'))
print (df)
   w1  w2  w3  w4  w5  w6  w7  w8  w9  B  C
0   2   5   8   4   2   3   1   2   8  3  4
1   5   1   4   3   8   3   1   2   3  5  3
```